# IndexedDB search for key and sort

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

At the moment i have 2 functions. One for querying the DB for results with a specific key/value pair and one for getAll rows sorted by a specific key.
Is there a way combine these two ? So i want to have a function where you search a store for objects where a=1 sorted by b asc .

Function to get results by index:

```
getByIndex : function(store,indexKey,indexValue,callback){
    var results = [];
    this._initTransaction(store,"readonly",function(err,transaction){

        var index = transaction.objectStore(store).index(indexKey);
        index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(indexValue)).onsuccess = function(event) {
          var cursor = event.target.result;
          if (cursor) {
            results.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
          } else {
            callback(true,results);
          }
        };
    })  
}
```

Function to get results sorted by key:

```
getSorted : function(store,sortKey,callback){
    var results = [];
    this._initTransaction(store,"readonly",function(err,transaction){

        var index = transaction.objectStore(store).index(sortKey);
        index.openCursor(null,'next').onsuccess = function(event) {
            var cursor = event.target.result;
          if (cursor) {
            results.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
          } else {
            callback(true,results);
          }
        };
    })      
},
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index on the two properties:

```
function myOnUpgradeNeeded(event) {
  // ...
  var index = store.createIndex('myIndex', ['a', 'b']);
}
```

Define a function that opens a bounded cursor over the index and iterate:

```
function query(db, a, callback) {
  if(!a) {
    throw new TypeError('this only works if a is defined');
  }

  var results = [];
  var tx = db.transaction('store');
  tx.oncomplete = function(event) {
    callback(results);
  };
  var store = tx.objectStore('store');
  var index = store.index('myIndex');

  var lowerBound = [a];

  // How you define the upper bound depends on the type. This assumes 
  // that a is a number. For example, if a is a string, you need to 
  // use a different boundary definition. See the gist by Mr. Bell 
  // below for an example of how to create other types of bounds. You 
  // simply need to determine whatever is the 'next' value that would 
  // come after `a`s value in your data.
  var upperBound = [a+1];

  var range = IDBKeyRange.bound(lowerBound, upperBound, false, true);
  var request = index.openCursor(range);
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor) {
      results.push(cursor.value);
      cursor.continue();
    }
  };
}
```

And then call it:

```
var request = indexedDB.open(...);
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  query(db, 1, function(results) {
    // ...
  });
};
```

This compares array keypaths of different lengths, so even though the index is defined on [a,b], the range only compares [a]...[a+1]. It is perfectly ok to compare array keypaths of different lengths, the comparison only compares values up to the length of the shorter array.

The order of entries in the index is per [a,b]. So if you limit the index entries to those containing a, then you obtain a subset ordered by b where every a is the target a, which is what I understand to be the objective.

Comment: To do where "a=1 sorted by b asc" you want an index on `['a', 'b']`, then you can open a cursor on `IDBKeyRange.bound([1], [2], false, true)`. If you invert the index (as you have) you'll see values with a != 1. Want to take a stab at updating your answer?

Comment: Thanks Josh, I think I fixed it. Do you have enough points yet to edit the response? You're welcome to if you do.

Comment: Still not quite right: IDBKeyRange.bound([a],[a]) is a key range containing only one possible key - it's not a prefix match. I'll toss in the +1

Comment: And note that it does mean this only works for numeric keys as written. For a more general solution (a range representing a prefix match) see https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/5462871

Comment: I approved your edit. I plan to look into the comments more in a bit here. Thanks again!

Comment: Side note if anyone comes here later, use getAll for better performance over building an array and walking a cursor.